# Linear Regression: Implementing numpy operations from scratch, gradient increasing to infinity

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

Below I implemented the gradient descent function found [here](https://medium.com/@lope.ai/multivariate-linear-regression-from-scratch-in-python-5c4f219be6a). (Method: batch_gradient_descent) I wanted to try and implement it without numpy because I don't know numpy arrays well and I want to intuitively understand the required operations.

I created a simple linear relation in lists x and y such that y0 = 5x0+1. x is initially a list of two element lists of n elements and y is a st of n elements. The second element of x is 1 to account for the bias weight. The weights are initialized to [0,0].

**I think my issue is in GetGradient()** as I have tested GetHypothesis() - a dot product operation between the weights and each 2-element input list- and  Subtract1d() -  both of which are easy enough to verify on run 1 of the loop when the weights are 0.

**GetGradient()** calculates X.T.dot(loss) / m found in their tutorial, which is what this method implements. But I don't know where I am going wrong. Gradient shuffles off to nan-land pretty soon after 10 iterations.

First ever posted question, so I appreciate the help.

```py
def dot(K, L):
   if len(K) != len(L):
      return False
   return sum(i[0] * i[1] for i in zip(K, L))
def GetHypothesis(input,weights):
    hyp = []
    for i in range(len(input)):
        d = dot(input[i],weights)
        hyp.append(d)
    return hyp
def Subtract1D(hyp,act):
    loss = []
    for i in range (len(hyp)):
        loss.append(hyp[i]-act[i])
    return loss
def GetGradient(x,loss):
    col1 = []
    col2 = []
    for ele in x:
        col1.append(ele[0])
        col2.append(ele[1])
    
    w1 = dot(col1,loss)
    w2 = dot(col2,loss)
    w1 = w1/len(x)
    w2 = w2/len(x)
    return [w1, w2]
def GradientDescent(x,y,w,lr=0.1):
    for i in range(10):
        # hypothesis
        h = GetHypothesis(x,w)
        loss = Subtract1D(h,y)

        gradientVector = []

        grad = GetGradient(x,loss)
        
        grad[0] = grad[0]*lr
        grad[1] = grad[1]*lr

        w[0] = (w[0]  - grad[0])
        w[1] = (w[1]  - grad[1])
        print(grad)
    return w
x = list(range(1,50))
y = [i*5+1 for i in x]
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = [x[i],1]
w = [0,0]

GradientDescent(x,y,w)
```

Comment: FYI a linear regression (without penalization) has a closed form solution. There is no need for doing gradient descent. Gradient descent for linear regression is a waste of everything.

Comment: @j1-lee Yes. Though wasteful is subjective, I feel. It's simply for my own educational purposes. Is that to say that gradient descent won't work and that is why my gradient is wildly incorrect?